# Android: Widget load images

Tags: android, android-widget, android-asynctask, imageview

I am unable to fiund how to download images to my widget!

In my widget I load in AsyncTask json with url, title, then I show title in TextView and I need to load images from url.

I tried with this but image load, and now showing

```
class LoadImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>{
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            BufferedOutputStream out = null;

            try {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://mysite/simple.img").openStream());

                final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream);
                out.flush();

                final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                //options.inSampleSize = 1;

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
                Log.e("Log", "Yeah");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Log", "Could not load Bitmap from: " + "mysiteg");
            }

            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

And on Update I call this

```
        LoadImages load = new LoadImages();
        load.execute();
        Bitmap bitmap = load.get();
        update.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView0, bitmap);
```

Comment: Make sure that image is residing on that url..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override onPostExecute method in LoadImages class, and set bitmap to your ImageView in that method. When LoadImages task is done, it will call onPostExcute method. Considering WeakReference to wrap your ImageView for better performance.